# How to tile a background image for splash screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, splash-screen

In general, that's all... I just can't get how to tile a background image for splash screen in **Unity3D**?

Now it stretches image to fill screen. I tried to switch **Wrap Mode** to **Repeat** for the background image but it didn't help. Is it possible in **Unity3D** to tile a splash background?

**ADDED**
I mean a splash background image in **Player Settings** on **Android** tab in **Unity3D 2018.3.12f1**.

[image: Splash settings]

**P.S.** Image isn't white, it has a gray grid with thin edges.

Comment: Yes it is possible, what exactly are you using for your image?

Comment: @Eddge I use **Sprite** type, Unity doesn't accept **Texture**.

Comment: So you are using a Sprite Component for your splash screen?  Or are you using an Image Component on the UI for your splash screen? Either way the answer I provided below says how to tile.

Comment: I updated my answer, in regards to the splash screen settings itself I do not believe there is a way to do a "Tile background"  However if you check my answer I suggest an alternative to the "Unity Splash" Screen.

Comment: @Eddge, thank you for answer! It looks as required feature so I thought it is supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Splash Screen settings in the editor, I do not believe there is a way to tile it there, what I would do instead is create a sceen for your Splash Screen, and use one of the following for it.  This has several advantages over the Unity Splash Screen.

Such as the ability to fully animate the screen as much as you want, to load static objects that need to exist only once and throughout your entire project.

Old Answer Below:

Tiling an image for your splash screen can be done a number of ways depending on what you are using:

**Sprite:**

Change the Draw mode on the Sprite Renderer to Tile, then Change the Width and Height.

**Image:**

Set your texture change the Image Type to Tile.

**A quad:**

Depending on the material you are using, you should be able to go to the bottom of it and change the tiling options.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, I didn't explain where I use this image. I've added more details.